# Function with discrete domain and range, does order matter?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, notation

Say I have the function
$$
f:\{0,1\} \rightarrow\{0,1\}
$$
**Q1:** Does the order of the elements in the domain och the range matter?

I.e. does this notation mean we only have 
$f(0)=0$ and
$f(1)=1$?

Or could we have $f(1)=0$ and
$f(0)=1$?

**Q2:** And what about a more general case, 
$$
g:\{0,1, 2, \dots, n\} \rightarrow \{0,1, 2, \dots, n\}
$$
Does this mean we only have $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=1$, $g(n)=n$ etc.?

Or can we for instance have $g(1)=n$, $g(0)=n-1$, $g(10)=5$ and so on?

Comment: No. $\{0,1\} = \{1,0\}$, etc. The notation just describes a set containing the listed elements.

Comment: You could even have a map $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ for $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1$.